# React native expo init issue

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to learn react native and now I'm stuck when I run command: expo init my-app.

I have installed node and expo in my computer but when I want to create a new react native app, receive an error:

expo : The term 'expo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- expo
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (expo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

What should I do to fix that problem?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm i -g expo-cli` or `npm install --global expo-cli` in the terminal.

Install Expo globally first. This error occurred because `expo` was not installed globally.

Also, check whether you have `npm` folder added correctly to your path under `Environment Variables`

Comment: I removed expo and after that I reinstall expo globally but the error it's same.

Comment: check whether you have `npm` folder added correctly to your path under `Environment Variables`

Comment: Run `node -v` in the terminal and see what output you get in the `console`